# Constructor question in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I write two constructors like these below:

```
Person(name, age) { 
    this.name = name;  
    this.age = age;  
    sayName = function() {  
        alert("hello");  
    };
}
```

and

```
Person(name, age) { 
    this.name = name;  
    this.age = age;  
    this.sayName = function() {  
        alert("hello");  
    };
}
```

What is the difference? Does

> sayName

really mean something in the first code? Is it useful?

Comment: When you're asking questions about books, please include information about the work. It helps people help you, as well as correctly attributing the code. In this case, the example is from *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, Second Edition* by Nicholas C. Zakas (Wrox, 2009), page 152.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sayName` in the first code is a <strike>private</strike> global function, while in second it's a privileged public function.

---

Update#1:

The following code pretty much summarizes what they mean

```
function Person(name, age) { 
    this.name = name;  
    this.age = age;  
    sayName = function() {  //define in global name-space
    alert("hello");  
    }  

    var sayNamePvt = function() { //private function
        alert("hello pvt");  
    }  

    this.callPvt = function(){ //shows how privilege function can access private vars and functions
        sayNamePvt();
    }
}


function Person1(name, age) { 
    this.name = name;  
    this.age = age;  
    this.sayName = function() { //privilege public function  
        alert("hello1");  
    }  
}


var one = new Person('abc', 12);
var two = new Person1('abcd', 11);
two.sayName();//privileged public access
sayName(); //global access
//one.sayName(); //ERROR: one.sayName is not a function
//one.sayNamePvt(); //ERROR: one.sayNamePvt is not a function
one.callPvt(); //privileged method can call private functions
```

Comment: actually since there's no `var` keyword it's a global function

Comment: @qwertymk woops. missed the fine-line.

Comment: @jsnewman updated answer, apology for the messed up answer earlier.